# Update last path on the URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, path

I doing a filter system with pagination and i am in a trouble trying to redirect with Javascript depending on the current URL.

I can have this types of URLs where the last number is a filter:

```
http://localhost/posts/yourPosts/1
http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/3
```

And inside each type, page 2 will be shown in this way:

```
http://localhost/posts/yourPosts/1/page:2?url=posts%2FyourPosts
http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/3/page:2?url=posts%2FSubscriptions
```

I am currently using:

```
window.location.href = currentURL + '/' + encodeURI($(this).val());
```

Where $(this).val is the number of the filter to use.

The problem is that when i am in this URLs it works well:

```
http://localhost/posts/yourPosts/
http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/
```

But when i am in the 2nd page and i want to show the filter number 3 (lets say, cars instead of animals), it doesn't. It show this:

```
http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/2/page:2?url=posts%2FyourPosts/3
```

Instead of this:

```
http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/3
```

Is there any simple way to deal with URLs to solve this kind of problem?

I can not either use an absolute path because the URLs are not all the same. So... is there any way to change the last PATH of a URL?

Answer (score 1):

quick and somewhat dirty:

```js
function fixmybadfilterurl(mybadurl)
{
    var parts = mybadurl.split('?');
    var subpart2 = parts[parts.length-1].split('/');
    var subpart1 = parts[0].split('/');
    subpart1.pop();
    subpart1.pop();
    return(subpart1.join('/')+'/'+subpart2[subpart2.length-1]);
}
```

so

```js
fixmybadfilterurl('http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/2/page:2?url=posts%2FyourPosts/3');
```

will return

```
'http://localhost/posts/subscriptions/3'
```